# text block in two columns with blank area

Tags: html, css

For example, I have 5 text blocks from A to E.

Then, I want to sort them to be like:

```
A
B   D
C   E
```

I've tried `display:inline-block` for B~E, but It would make

```
A 
B   C
D   E
```

Also, the text block is aligned from bottom when they have different number of lines.

Which I want to make them start in same line

[image: example]

`float` wouldn't even align as I wanted.

Would there be any way I could do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS flexbox layout. But for this case you need 2 static parameters (width and height) for wrapper

For more information use this link:
[Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
#wrapper{display:flex;flex-direction:column;height:80px;flex-wrap:wrap;width:50px;justify-content:flex-end}

/* FOR STYLING (OPTIONAL) */
#wrapper div{background-color:#f5f5f5;text-align:center;padding:2px;margin:2px}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only need of two columns, you could wrap each of it in an 'inline-block' element.

```
<div style="width:100%; display:block">A</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <div>B</div>
  <div>D</div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <div>C</div>
  <div>E</div>
</div>
```

This can be done using either css-grid or flexbox model also